# How to change CodeIgniter language

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have just started using CodeIgniter. Whenever I load any changes and if there is any error then message appears in French language instead English. I have looked at my `config.php` and there is this variable set: `$config['language'] = 'english';`. However, it does not make any difference.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is anything needs to be done in order to display messages in English.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your language file and see if the errors have English description. I think they have only French description.